# I can't send a button's id to another page in PHP

Tags: php, button, request, send

I'm creating a website like anyone can ask a question, and anyone can answer it. The site index is full of questions and answers.

I succeed asking a question part to mysql. I keep answers of all questions in different txt documents as answer_$id.txt.

My question is when i click answer button how can I $_REQUEST the id of the button so that I can add the answer to that id's txt document.

Comment: Use $_POST or $_GET do not use $_REQUEST.

Comment: What will I get in $_POST[???]

Comment: You can't get HTML element id in php, It's work with element name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple achieve this by using the hidden input type.

use the `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?> name="question_id"/>`

and you can take the id of question on submit the answer by `$_REQUEST`.
No need to add the question id in button's id.

Comment: I still didn't get it. value="<?=$id?>" are theese question marks neccesary?

Comment: And will I write as $_REQUEST[question_id]

Comment: @AlpanKaraca $id will be your question id for which you want to add the answer. I use $id as I don't know your variable name. you can use your variable. and yes you can get it by $_REQUEST['question_id'].

Comment: Thank you Broken Heart. Don't let anyone break your heart.